# Why are arrays indexed by datatype?

Tags: arrays, oracle10g, indexing

```
TYPE  emp_type_rec IS TABLE OF
employees%rowtype
INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

When we define an array, why is it indexed by some datatype?

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a choice of data types to index by.  For example:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE empno_rec_type IS TABLE OF employees.empno%type INDEX BY VARCHAR2(10);
    empno_rec empno_rec_type;
BEGIN
    empno_rec('SMITH') = 123;
    empno_rec('JONES') = 456;
END;
```